# remove excess space at the bottom of my pageview.builder widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to remove the excess space at the bottom of my widget but have not been able to do so. since I am using a page builder with a lot of text. I have tried adding the height manually but its not enough since i cant predict the size of the text.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_lorem/flutter_lorem.dart';
import 'package:blink/core/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:blink/feeds/feeds_details/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:blink/gen/assets.gen.dart';

class FeedsDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FeedsDetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const FeedsDetailView();
  }
}

class FeedsDetailView extends StatelessWidget {
  const FeedsDetailView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String text1 = lorem(paragraphs: 2, words: 55);
    final String text2 = lorem(paragraphs: 9, words: 500);
    final String text3 = lorem(paragraphs: 10, words: 400);
    final String text4 = lorem(paragraphs: 8, words: 2000);
    final String text5 = lorem(paragraphs: 12, words: 500);
    final textList = [
      text3,
      text4,
      text5,
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 368,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          //color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        child: Assets.images.nightBuilding.image(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 250,
                    left: 20,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 350,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .backgroundColor
                                    .computeLuminance() >
                                0.5
                            ? Colors.black
                            : Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: AppMediumText(text: text1),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 334,
                    right: 33,
                    child: ElevatedButtonSmall(
                      onpressed: () {},
                      text: '',
                      useIcon: true,
                      icon: Icons.account_balance,
                      fizedSize: const Size(50, 50),
                      radius: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 334,
                    right: 105,
                    child: ElevatedButtonSmall(
                      onpressed: () {},
                      text: '',
                      useIcon: true,
                      icon: Icons.text_fields,
                      fizedSize: const Size(50, 50),
                      radius: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Divider(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              indent: 50,
              endIndent: 50,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 380,
              height: double.maxFinite,
              child: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: textList.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == 0) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
               
                        const SizedBox(height: 14),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 350,
                            height: double.maxFinite,
                            child: AppSmallText(
                              text: text2.replaceFirst(
                                text2[0],
                                text2[0].toUpperCase(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        
                        const SizedBox(height: 14),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 350,
                            height: double.maxFinite,
                            child: AppSmallText(
                              text: textList[index - 1].replaceFirst(
                                textList[0],
                                textList[0].toUpperCase(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ignore this line it is just an excess line. I am trying to remove the excess space at the bottom of my widget but have not been able to do so. since I am using a page builder with a lot of text. I have tried adding the height manually but its not enough since i cant predict the size of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` in your columns and remove `height: double.maxFinite`:

```
class FeedsDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FeedsDetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const FeedsDetailView();
  }
}

class FeedsDetailView extends StatelessWidget {
  const FeedsDetailView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String text1 = lorem(paragraphs: 2, words: 55);
    final String text2 = lorem(paragraphs: 9, words: 500);
    final String text3 = lorem(paragraphs: 10, words: 400);
    final String text4 = lorem(paragraphs: 8, words: 2000);
    final String text5 = lorem(paragraphs: 12, words: 500);
    final textList = [
      text3,
      text4,
      text5,
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 368,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          //color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        child: Assets.images.nightBuilding.image(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 250,
                    left: 20,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 350,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .backgroundColor
                                    .computeLuminance() >
                                0.5
                            ? Colors.black
                            : Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: AppMediumText(text: text1),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 334,
                    right: 33,
                    child: ElevatedButtonSmall(
                      onpressed: () {},
                      text: '',
                      useIcon: true,
                      icon: Icons.account_balance,
                      fizedSize: const Size(50, 50),
                      radius: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 334,
                    right: 105,
                    child: ElevatedButtonSmall(
                      onpressed: () {},
                      text: '',
                      useIcon: true,
                      icon: Icons.text_fields,
                      fizedSize: const Size(50, 50),
                      radius: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Divider(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              indent: 50,
              endIndent: 50,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 380,
              child: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: textList.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == 0) {
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
               
                        const SizedBox(height: 14),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 350,
                            child: AppSmallText(
                              text: text2.replaceFirst(
                                text2[0],
                                text2[0].toUpperCase(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        
                        const SizedBox(height: 14),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 350,
                            child: AppSmallText(
                              text: textList[index - 1].replaceFirst(
                                textList[0],
                                textList[0].toUpperCase(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still the same result